# Get ObjectId of Azure Data Factory, within ARM template deployment output

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am deploying an `Azure Data Factory` using ARM templates. I need the `ObjectId/PricipalId/Managed Identity Object ID` of the Data Factory in the outputs of the deployment. This can be found on the Azure portal under `Properties` tab of a Data Factory

I have tried these variations but to no avail:

```
"value": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/', variables('name')), '2018-06-01').identity.principalId]"
"value": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/', variables('name')), '2018-06-01').principalId]"
```

The error that I get to see on using these is that the property (identity/principalId) does not exist

I have also tried out the stuff mentioned in the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#reference, it gave the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `reference(concat('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/', variables('name')), '2018-06-01', 'Full')` as the value for the output and examine it, you should see if what you need exists. if it does - reference it like you normally would, if it doesnt - you are out of luck.

Comment: I had actually used the `Full` parameter initially, but Visual Studio prompted that `reference` function accepts only 1 or 2 arguments! which is why I had removed it.

Comment: sadly, schema is garbage, dont trust it ;)

Answer (score 2):

The working output snippet is:

```
 "dataFactoryPrincipalId": {
  "type": "string",
  "value": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/', parameters('name')), '2018-06-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]"
}
```

**note this is not the same as the "Managed Identity Application ID" property**

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps anyone, I was facing this problem when deploying an ARM template that provisioned a Data Factory, then created a Key Vault access policy for it. The syntax was correct for the objectId property for the access policy, i.e.:

```
"[reference(concat('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/', parameters('dataFactoryName')), '2018-06-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]"
```

However it was still returning an error that the identity property was not available for the resource. The issue was that I was not provisioning an identity when I deployed the Data Factory. The following property needed to be added to the Data Factory deployment:

```
"identity": {
    "type": "SystemAssigned"
 }
```

Then the property was available to the reference function.